# Composing unicode char format for NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a list of unicode char "codes" that I'd like to print using `\u` escape sequence (e.g. `\ue415`), as soon as I try to compose it with something like this:

```
// charCode comes as NSString object from PList
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u%@", charCode];
```

the compiler warns me about incomplete character code. Can anyone help me with this trivial task?

Comment: You want to output unicode symbol with given code?

Comment: Yes and I have already tried the `%C` placeholder with no luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can't do that the way you're trying - \uxxx escape sequence is used to indicate that a constant is a unicode character - and that conversion is processed at compile-time.

What you need is to convert your charCode to an integer number and use that value as format parameter:

```
unichar codeValue = (unichar) strtol([charCode UTF8String], NULL, 16);
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", charCode];
NSLog(@"Character with code \\u%@ is %C", charCode, codeValue);
```

Sorry, that nust not be the best way to get int value from HEX representation, but that's the 1st that came to mind

**Edit:** It appears that `NSScanner` class can scan `NSString` for number in hex representation:

```
unichar codeValue;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:charCode] scanHexInt:&codeValue];
...
```

Comment: This was great help! THe only thing is that I get a warning on the second line as apparently unichar is not a valid type for the passing argument of the scanHexInt: function. It still works, but is is an annoying warning.

Comment: You need to use a bit of byte manipulation to get this NSScanner approach to work for higher unicode values > UFFFF... see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15133359/2308190

Answer (score 1):

Beware that not all characters can be encoded in UTF-8. I had a bug yesterday where some Korean characters were failing to be encoded in UTF-8 properly.

My solution was to change the format string from %s to %@ and avoid the re-encoding issue, although this may not work for you.

Comment: True, but here utf-8 is used just to convert string representation of character code to its integer value, resulting string itself may require be treated as unicode string

Comment: The issue I was running into was the bad UTF-8 encoding contained embeded null characters, so strtol will not give you what you are expecting.

Comment: I wanted to redisplay emoji characters from this url: http://pukupi.com/post/1964/ and Vladimir's code did the job. So I guess I'm out of the scope of this problem. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

Based on codes from @Vladimir, this works for me:

```
NSUInteger codeValue;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:@"0xf8ff"] scanHexInt:&codeValue];
NSLog(@"%C", (unichar)codeValue);
```

not leading by "\u" or "\\u", from API doc:

```
The hexadecimal integer representation may optionally be preceded
by 0x or 0X. Skips past excess digits in the case of overflow,
so the receiver’s position is past the entire hexadecimal representation.
```