# Where can I find the list of 'autoreplaceable' iOS special characters?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

Several special characters (⬇, for example) when being used in labels, etc are replaced with images automatically.

Where can I find the complete list of such replacements?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** I know that I can simply copy-paste a lot of special characters to define what are the magic ones but I am interesting whether this magic is documented anywhere?

---

***PROOF:***

*Source:*

```
UILabel *lbl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 200, 220, 25)] autorelease];
lbl.text = @"Did you see that? ⬇";
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
```

*Result:*

[image: result]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the "image" is actually an emoji icon. The iphone uses softbanks emoji encoding ranges, so here is the [list of those emoji](http://pukupi.com/post/1964) icons and their respective codes.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615506/composing-unicode-char-format-for-nsstring) on how to put those charcodes into use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eimantas. Those icons was a mystery for me until now :)