# Convert unicode

Tags: objective-c, unicode

I have a `UITextField` to enter a `unicode` value , when i tap a `UIButton` need to convert it and showing in a `UILabel`.
The below code is working fine for me(unicode inside my code):

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\u0D05"];
    m_CtrlLabel.text=str;
```

My problem is I can't convert the 4 digit unicode from the `UITextField`. That is I am typing `0D05` inside the `UITextField` , I need to convert it and show in the label ,  I have tried a lot of combinations but no luck.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you downvote ? Please comment the reason or provide the answer if this is not a useful question

Comment: Btw, Unicode values can have six hexadecimal digits.

Comment: I think you're confused. One shall provide the answer if this _is_ a useful question!

Comment: @Melbourne: Did any of the answers help? It would be nice to get some feedback.

Answer (score 4):

`0D05` is just a hexadecimal number. You can use `NSScanner` to parse the hexadecimal string into an integer, and then create a `NSString` containing the Unicode character.

```
NSString *hexString = yourInputField.text;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
uint32_t unicodeInt;
if ([scanner scanHexInt:&unicodeInt]) {
    unicodeInt = OSSwapHostToLittleInt32(unicodeInt); // To make it byte-order safe
    NSString *unicodeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&unicodeInt length:4 encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
    yourOutputLabel.text = unicodeString;
} else {
    // Conversion failed, invalid input.
}
```

This works even with Unicodes > U+FFFF, such as `1F34C` (thanks to R. Martinho Fernandes for his feedback).

Comment: This won't work if the user types 1F34C, for example, in order to get a [lovely banana](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f34c/browsertest.htm) .

Comment: EXCELLENT, there are incomplete solutions to this all over stackoverflow and the internet... this is the first one that works for those larger unicode values like lovely banana!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is input should be char pointer

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[self.textField.text UTF8String]];
    m_CtrlLabel.text=str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the font of your `UILable`.
Actually some fonts can't display all unicode outputs!
This happened to me in `Java Swing` once!
I was trying to display a `unicode` string on a `JLabel` but the unicode string wasn't being displayed on `JLablel`.
Then I changed the font to `Arial` the unicode values got displayed!
So I'd suggest you to try changing the font from to `Arial` or some other font.

Hope this helps!