# Convert NSString to unicode with escape

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsstring

```
NSString *string1 = @"\u03C0";
NSLog(@"string1: %@", string1);  // result of a Pi symbol

NSString *string2 = @"03C0";
NSString *string3 = [@"\\u" stringByAppendingString:string2];
NSLog(@"string3: %@", string3);  // result of \u03C0 but need it to be a Pi symbol as well
```

I would think string3 would give the same result as string1.  But It does not.  Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you type in a string literal with `\u9999`, this is treated as a special character literal by the compiler. The compiler will convert that syntax directly to the resulting character.

Your `string3` is being handled at runtime. The `\u9999` syntax has no special meaning at runtime.

You can do this:

```
NSString *string2 = @"03C0";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string2];
unsigned int code;
[scanner scanHexInt:&code];
NSString *string3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unsigned short)code];
NSLog(@"string3: %@", string3);
```

If you know the code is `\u03C0` then you can use it directly:

```
NSString *string3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unsigned short)0x03C0];
NSLog(@"string3: %@", string3);
```

Better yet, type it in directly:

```
NSString *string3 = @"π";
NSLog(@"string3: %@", string3);
```

Comment: You need to use a bit of byte manipulation to get this NSScanner approach to work for higher unicode values > UFFFF... see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15133359/2308190

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in your question.

You say this as UNICODE Character \u03C0, not as UNICODE string.

Therefore as you use `stringByAppendingString:` it returns a `string` to `string3`, not the character.

Answer (score 2):

`\u03C0` is *one* single Unicode character, i.e. just another representation for the pi character. A string of the characters '\','u', etc. is a different thing.